# Qt C++ если не удалось найти программу по умолчанию

Tags: c++, qt

Привет всем! Интересует решение данного вопроса. Есть код:

```
QString path = QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/readme/1.pdf";
```

Далее использую проверку на существование файла

```
if(!File::exists(path)) {
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox(trUtf8("Невозможно открыть файл") + path + trUtf8(" Файл не существует!"));
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

Запуск файла:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(path, QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

А теперь вопрос... Как сделать проверку, если программы что бы открыть файл на компьютере нет? Сейчас, если нет программы, выводится окошко Windows не удалось открыть файл: Поиск соответствия в интернете, Выбор программы из списка установленных программ. Я хочу сделать так что бы выводился `MessageBox` если программы, с помощью которой файл можно открыть, на компьютер не установлена. Проверка в стиле:

```
if(!QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(path, QUrl::TolerantMode)))
```

не помогает. Выводится 2е такое же окно что и выше, с Windows, т.е их становится 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Открываете `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf` читаете там дефолтный параметр, например там будет "AcroExch.Document.DC". Потом открываете `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AcroExch.Document.DC\shell\Open\command` и читаете дефолтный параметр там. Там будет путь к программе для открытия PDF. Если нет первого или второго ключа - дефолтной программы для открытия нет.

Comment: Спасибо. А не подскажешь, как реализовать данную проверку и под linux? Где там подобные данные хранятся? нужно кроссплатформенное решение.

Comment: @Disastricks Скорее всего не выйдет, потому что сам Linux вообще ничего не знает о PDF. В KDE могут быть одни настройки открытия, в GNOME - вторые, в blackbox вообще не будет файлового менеджера и настроек, а mc работает по-своему.